# one to one transformation for the bivariate case.

Tags: probability, statistics

give the joint pdf:
$ f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
1,  &  0<x<1,~~0<y<1,\\
0, & elsewhere 
\end{cases}$
let $Z=XY$ $~~~~$ find the cdf of Z ?
I tried to use the transformation them to find the pdf and it did not work,
So, I use the cdf technique to find pdf and it works, then I asked my teacher and he said that because the transformation function is not one to one.

My question how did he know is not one to one in this case?

for the univariate case it is easy to check if the transformation is one-to-one 
but how can I check for the bivariate case?

Comment: If we define $g(x,y) = xy$, then $g(x,y) = g(y,x)$ but $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ may be different.

Comment: I really can not see that. I mean in univariate case we just take the derivative and see where it decrease or increase. However in bivariate case  I  do not know how to think about it

Comment: got it , i understand what you mean by $If~ we~ define~ g(x,y)=xy~~ then~ g(x,y)~=~g(y,x)~ ~but~ (x,y)~and (y,x) may be different$